# SSIS Web services - Write to web services

Tags: web-services, ssis

I have successfully able to consume using web services task in SSIS , but I am not able to figure out  how to write to web service , can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: I do believe that "reading" refers to "calling", which means that the operation the web service is doing could either be reading or writing, who knows?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide a sample of code that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit too vague to give a definitive answer to, but,  taking a guess at what you're asking, is that you've been able to read data from a web service (GET) but you now want to write (POST/PUT) data to a web service.

If so, your best bet is to use a Script task and use C# (or VB) to call said web service. I would also recommend this for GET requests, too, as opposed to the SSIS Web Service task, which doesn't handle "newer" web service protocols, such as oAuth authentication.

Rough sample would be as follows:

```
      using System.Net
      using System.IO          

      string url 
            = "http://webservicehere.org";

        // create the request
        HttpWebRequest request 
            = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        // set the method to POST
        request.Method 
            = "POST";

        // set the content type, usually application/json or application/xml
        request.ContentType 
            = "application/json";

        // handle authentication, in this case the web service
        // requires the authentication token to be passed in as a
        // header called "Cookie"
        request.Headers.Add("Cookie", SqlAuthCookie);

        // get the stream object to use to write the request data
        StreamWriter requestWriter 
            = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());

        // write the data to the web service
        // where (data) is the JSON/XML that you are
        // sending to the endpoint
        requestWriter.Write(data);

        // close the connection upon completion
        requestWriter.Close();

        try
        {
            // read the response received from the web service
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // code to handle the response goes here
            // i.e. deserialise json/xml to strongly typed objects

        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            // catch any exceptions thrown by the web service here
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // catch other exceptions here
        }
```